# Is there a way to make Material ui Card without border

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have read the documentation the option to make it `variant="outlined"` or to make it `raised`

But is there a way to make the card without visible border at all?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can give inline styling to your card, giving border and box shadow property as none.

```js
<Card style={{ border: "none", boxShadow: "none" }}>
    ....
</Card>
```

Another way to do it is by using `makeStyles` from `@material-ui/core/styles` and styling a class which could be given to the card.

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  custom: {
    border: "none",
    boxShadow: "none"
  }
});

const classes = useStyles();
.
.
.
return (
  <Card className={classes.custom}>
    ....
  </Card>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to remove the border from card is by setting elevation to 0

```
<Card elevation={0}>
    Your content
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that to remove border radius on Cards. You can simply add `square={true}` to Card Component.

```
<Card square={true}>
    Your content
</Card>
```

You can also read the documentation, If you wanted.
[Material Ui Paper Api](https://material-ui.com/api/paper/)